# Access Postgresql on cloud9 remotely

Tags: postgresql, cloud9-ide

I have created a new postgresql-database on cloud9.

Is it possible to access postgresql-databases that are hosted on cloud9 remotely with the pgAdmin-tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way to connect to a Postgres db on Cloud9 from a desktop application (though we are considering adding support for that in the future). Some web-based applications I can recommend are [phpPgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php) and [AdMiner](http://www.adminer.org/). [Here's another list of Postgres tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a cloud9 employee answered how to do this on their forum here:
https://community.c9.io/t/how-to-setup-pgadmin-iii-for-postgresql/2575